# Stripping strings in order to sort rows in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a master CSV file that looks something like this -- it's only 1 column.

```
column_name
string1010string
string1013string
string1014string
string1015string
string1016string
string1018string
string1020string
```

Then I have a temporary CSV that I would like to keep track of separtely but also merge it with the master CSV and have it sorted in ascending order only taking the integers into consideration. I am aware that I have to strip the strings (from the start & the end) of each row to isolate the integers and then sort but I'm not quite sure how to approach it after that.

```
column_name
string1011string
string1012string
string1017string
string1019string
```

My function looks something like this:

```
def output_master_concatenated(list1, list2):
    master= pd.concat([list1, list2])
    #sorting_system
    master.to_csv(str('master' + '.csv'), index = False, sep = ' ')
    return master
```

Ideally, this is what I would like it to look like.

```
column_name
string1010string
string1011string
string1012string
string1013string
string1014string
string1015string
string1016string
string1017string
string1018string
string1019string
string1020string
```

update: string(integer)string is actually a link, each row is basically the same link with only the integer changing

Comment: is the `string` part literal or variable? Fixed length? Alpha only? etc. Can you update your question to reflect this?

Comment: @mozway I have updated my post. Sorry for not being clear, it's my 2nd ever post and I wanted to be brief.

Comment: can you provide an example? It matters if the link contains numbers

Comment: @mozway is right. You can take advantage of the string format like `http://www.company.tld/path/to/1010/page.php` or `http://www.compagny.tld/path/to/page.php?id=1010`

Comment: or if you link is unfortunately like `'http://www2.example3.tld/4/x/1234'`

Comment: I forgot to mention this, sorry.

The link looks something like this:

ooo.ooo/ooo10000_1_ooooooo.ooo

The "_1_" is found in every link, ONLY the integer before the first underscore changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sort_values` with a custom key:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])

num_sort = lambda x: x.str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).str.zfill(10)
df = df.sort_values('column_name', key=num_sort, ignore_index=True)
print(df)

# Output
         column_name
0   string1010string
1   string1011string
2   string1012string
3   string1013string
4   string1014string
5   string1015string
6   string1016string
7   string1017string
8   string1018string
9   string1019string
10  string1020string
```

Comment: blind guessing I see :p I was waiting to get more info ;) I would use the same approach +1